# Help: Need to prove that $|G| = 18$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

if $f : G → \mathbb{Z}_6$ is a surjective morphism and $|Ker(f)| = 3$ prove that $|G| = 18$.

Comment: have you encountered the "first isomorphism theorem"?

Comment: $|G|=|image||kernel|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem, $f(G)\cong G/\rm{ker}f$.  Therefore $|G|/3=6\implies |G|=18$.

Comment: It looks good, thanks

Comment: Yeah.  It goes right through.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this without appealing to one of these fundamental theorems. It is pretty easy to get the cases to be $9,12,15,18$,...but I fear it would require rebuilding these theorems anyways since it is pretty clear cut they lead straight to the answer by themselves.

Comment: @DerekLuna  Honestly I don't know.  Somebody around here probably does though.